# Explanation for a minute error

Tags: geometry

[image: Question]

By using the provided value of $a$, we can calculate $h$ with two equations

$2h^2=a^2$

$h /\ cos45=a$

Both gives a different value for $h$ where the difference in the values although is of the magnitude $10^{-15}$ but still is there.

Can somebody provide an explanation for this discrepancy?

P.S. I tried using radian angles but the problem still persists.

Comment: If you are using a computer or calculator to find the value, then such errors are common. They occur because of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding).

Comment: Even the exact forms are different. Evaluated using wolfram alpha

Comment: Clearly, you're doing something that is encountering a limitation of your software, because mathematically the two quantities are identical. I don't think you'll get an explanation of why this caused a difference until you show us exactly what you did--and I mean _exactly_ what you did (for example if you got a result in Wolfram Alpha, show the exact input letter for letter).

Answer (score 2):

> By using the provided value of $a$, we can calculate $h$ with two equations
>
> $2h^2=a^2$

This is correct, and follows from Pythagoras' theorem: $\,h^2+h^2=a^2\,$.

> $h \cos45=a$

This is wrong, the correct equation is $\,h = a \cos 45^\circ\,$. Given that $\,\cos 45^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\,$, the equation is equivalent to $\,h = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} \iff h^2 = \frac{a^2}{2} \iff 2h^2 = a^2\,$ i.e. the same as the first equation.

Since $\,\sin 30^\circ = \frac{1}{2}\,$ and $\,\sin 15^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}\,$ by the half-angle formula, $\,h = 5 (\sqrt{3}-1)$ $\simeq 3.66\dots$

---

[ *EDIT* ]   The following is a followup on OP's comment:

> Put both of these equations in wolfram alpha. The exact value it provided is different for both.

The exact forms are *displayed* differently (for reasons only WA knows), but they both represent the same number since $\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{3}-1\,$.

As for the numerical values, I do not see the discrepancy there. Below are the results after clicking "*more digits*" a few times, and they agree to the $54^{th}$ decimal.

- [`solve 2 x^2 = ( 10 sin(15) / sin(30) )^2 for x`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%202%20x%5E2%20%3D%20(%2010%20sin(15)%20%2F%20sin(30)%20)%5E2%20for%20x)

[image]

- [`solve x / cos(45) = 10 sin(15) / sin(30) for x`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%20%2F%20cos(45)%20%3D%2010%20sin(15)%20%2F%20sin(30)%20for%20x)

[image]

Comment: Oh sorry yes that was a typo. Can you clear one thing? Put both of these equations in wolfram alpha. The exact value it provided is different for both.

Comment: @FaiqRaees Edited the WA links and snapshots into the answer.